# Upload a file from the Internet directly to a remote host through WinSCP

Tags: curl, wget, scp, winscp

Is there a way to directly upload a file (with an Internet address) to a Linux machine using WinSCP? I don't want to download to my local machine, and then upload  to the Linux server - I will like to do download directly: Internet -> Linux machine.

I already tried wget and curl -O, but the downloaded file is complete, so I am trying other methods like WinSCP.

```
>  wget https://www.kaggle.com/c/data-science-bowl-2017/download/stage1_labels.csv.zip
> --2017-04-01 17:22:04--  https://www.kaggle.com/c/data-science-bowl-2017/download/stage1_labels.csv.zip
> Resolving www.kaggle.com (www.kaggle.com)... 168.62.224.124 Connecting
> to www.kaggle.com (www.kaggle.com)|168.62.224.124|:443... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found Location:
> /account/login?ReturnUrl=%2fc%2fdata-science-bowl-2017%2fdownload%2fstage1_labels.csv.zip
> [following]
> --2017-04-01 17:22:05--  https://www.kaggle.com/account/login?ReturnUrl=%2fc%2fdata-science-bowl-2017%2fdownload%2fstage1_labels.csv.zip
> Reusing existing connection to www.kaggle.com:443. HTTP request sent,
> awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 15671 (15K) [text/html] Saving to:
> ‘stage1_labels.csv.zip’
> 
> 100%[=================================================================================>] 15,671      --.-K/s   in 0.03s
> 
> 2017-04-01 17:22:05 (441 KB/s) - ‘stage1_labels.csv.zip’ saved
> [15671/15671]
```

The target file is 67 GB in size.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the other machine where you want to download the file using `ssh` and run the `wget` there. It will get transfered only once using the HTTPS protocol (which is fast). SFTP is generally very slow.

Comment: The output as shown above comes from wget on the that machine.